# uitableview] how to prevent users from scrolling before data is fully loaded?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm currently working on a tableview using MBProgressHUD & NSURLConnection.
The problem is that when a user is at 80th row for example and there are like only 10 rows exist when the table is refreshed with less data, this app totally crashes cuz the row that the user is looking at leads to a released 80th row - bad memory access error.

I'd like to make sure that no matter where the user is at, the app should not crash. What would be the best way to correct this problem? :S

Comment: This doesn't seem table view related. If you reload with less info, the tableview should just scroll to wherever the bottom row is. Can you maybe post the error log you are getting.

Comment: I didn't know that before :) Many thanks to you as well!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Bergasms is right, your problem is not related to the table being scrolled, disabling it in this situation is probably unwise (from a design perspective). With that said you can use the [`scrollEnabled`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/scrollEnabled) property and set it to `NO`

To resolve your crash however you should be calling `[self.tableView reloadData]` as soon as the datasource is updated.

Also your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` should return the count from the object backing your datasource.

Here is an example implementation that shows updating the datasource while scrolling does not cause a crash if done correctly.

```
@interface CLViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *stuffs;

@end

@implementation CLViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.stuffs = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        [self.stuffs addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i]];
    }

    int64_t delayInSeconds = 3.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [self.stuffs removeAllObjects];
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            [self.stuffs addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i]];
            [self.theTableView reloadData];
        }
    });
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.stuffs.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"StuffCell"];
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.stuffs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

@end
```

This loads 100 rows into the `stuffs` array on `viewDidLoad` which is immediately scrollable on app launch. After 3 seconds the `stuffs` array is emptied and loaded with 10 items, next `[self.theTableView reloadData];` is called, the interaction is a little jolting but basically the last 90 rows just disappear and all is well, no crash.

Comment: You were right. It was one of my arrays causing such a trouble, not the table itself. Updating an image array was slower than reloading the tableview and that was where bad memory access was occuring. Many thanks to you!